# Does Angular 6.x supports core-js 3.x version

Tags: angular

Does Angular-6 verison supports core-js(3.31.1) or core-js (3.x)?

i tried by using Angular 6 with core-js 3.31.1 but variables which are used to store in the local storage is not working properly so i need to know Angular 6 will support core-js 3.31.1 or not.

Answer (score 0):

From Angular's `package.json` on `6.1.10`, it requires `"core-js": "^2.4.1"`

Comment: Is there any documentation from Angular website, if its there can u send the screenshot pls.

Comment: I checked the latest v6 branch : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.x/package.json

Comment: Did anywhere they said for Angular 6 we can't use core-js 3.x version in original angular website or documentation.

Comment: This is the closest you will get : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13954#issuecomment-485822832. Angular dropped the codejs dependency long ago.